# Flutter: Failed in version solving pubget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

> Note: meta is pinned to version 1.10.0 by integration_test from the flutter SDK.
> See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.

> Because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on meta 1.10.0 and every version of split_bills from path depends on meta 1.9.1, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with split_bills from path.
> So, because consumer depends on both split_bills from path and integration_test from sdk, version solving failed.

How to fix above error?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this issue without delving deep is to remove the version number of the questioned package and flutter automatically selects the compatible version and adds it to the project.

i.e.

```
split_bills:
integration_test:
consumer:
```

This should fix the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now on running tests, target dart file not found. But actually file is available in project. Not sure whats the issue

Comment: got error in import path like this and I'm so new to flutter by the way.  Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:fixnum/fixnum.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist

Comment: in this case, the package fixnum was not added properly, try adding it to pubspec and run `flutter pub get` again

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it by 2 ways

1- if split_bills are a local package on your pc, just update the dependencies,
upgrade it to a version that supports meta 1.10.0

2- use ovverides on your poroject yaml file

```
dependency_overrides:
  meta: 1.10.0
```

Comment: Now its different error that target file not found. But actually its there in repo

Comment: add the error message with screenshots to be able to see the error

Answer (score 0):

Your post is not very clear. I'm assuming you mean that you want to find the  version of flutter used in your project? If so, you can go to your pubspec.yaml file, and you should see the version of flutter used in the first few lines. Mine says 'sdk: '>=3.1.3 <4.0.0'. This version number should be listed right under 'environment:'.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I dont want flutter version. I want to resolve version incompatible as mentioned in error message

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My answer, in my opinion, is quite clear. It may not have answered the poster's question, but that is because the poster did not write a good question, thus I had no way of making sure of what he wanted.